Exercise 8.8 Ljungqvist and Sargent, Corner Solutions
This question is exercise 8.8 from Ljungqvist and Sargent "Recursive Macroeconomic Theory" 3rd edition.

I repeat the question here for clarity.
There is a pure endowment economy and two types of consumer, $i=1,2$. The type-$1$ consumers have utility $$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t c_t^1$$ and the type-2 consumers have utility $$\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta \ln c_t^2$$ We enforce that $c_t^i\geq 0$ and $\beta\in (0,1)$. The type-1 consumer has endowment stream $$y_t^1=\mu>0 \qquad \forall t\geq 0$$ and the type-2 consumer has endowment stream $$y_t^2=\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{  if } t\geq 0 \text{ is even} \\
    \alpha & \text{ if } t\geq 0 \text{ is odd}
\end{cases}$$
We assume the consumption good is tradable but not storable. Agents have access to a complete set of Arrow-Debreu securities which are traded only at date $t=0$.
The question asks to solve for the competitive equilibrium in the case when $\alpha=\mu (1+\beta^{-1})$ and when $\alpha>\mu (1+\beta^{-1})$. It focuses on the implied one-period gross interest rates, asking whether they change between even and odd periods, and whether they are higher or lower when $\alpha>\mu (1+\beta^{-1})$ versus when $\alpha=\mu (1+\beta^{-1})$.

I first solve when $\alpha= \mu(1+\beta^{-1})$.
The Lagrangian for agent $i$'s problem at date $0$ is $$\mathcal{L}^i=\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t u^i(c_t^i) -\lambda^i\left[\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} q_t^0(c_t^i-y_t^i)\right]+\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \mu_t^i c_t^i$$ where $q_t^0$ is the price on the Arrow-Debreu security at date $0$ for one unit of the consumption good at date $t$. This has FOC $$0=\beta^t (u^i)'(c_t^i)-\lambda^i q_t^0 +\mu_t^i$$ as $\mu_t^i\geq 0$ and is strict if and only if $c_t^i>0$, our FOC is $$\beta^t(u^i)'(c_t^i)\leq \lambda^i q_t^0$$ For the two types this is \begin{align*}
    \beta^t &\leq \lambda^1 q_t^0 \qquad (i=1) \\
    \beta^t\frac{1}{c_t^2} &\leq \lambda^2 q_t^0 \qquad (i=2)
\end{align*}
Because $\lim_{c_t^2\to 0}\frac{1}{c_t^2}\to \infty$, the type-2 consumer will never set $c_t^2=0$, so their FOC holds with equality. For the type-1 consumer, if $\beta^t < \lambda^1 q_t^0$ then $c_t^1=0$ and if $\beta^t = \lambda^1 q_t^0$, $c_t^1$ may take any value in $[0,\infty )$ as the type-1 consumer. So, our FOCs become (with some abuse of notation), \begin{align*}
    c_t^1&=\begin{cases}
        0 & \text{ if } \beta^t < \lambda^1 q_t^0  \\
        [0,\infty) & \text{ if } \beta^t = \lambda^1 q_t^0 
    \end{cases} \\
    c_t^2&=\frac{\beta^t}{q_t^0}\frac{1}{\lambda^2}
\end{align*} I make the conjecture that $$q_t^0=\beta^t \text{  and   } \lambda^2=\frac{1}{\mu}$$ Thus, by the per-period endowment constraint \begin{align*}
    c_{2t+1}^1 &=\mu (1+\beta^{-1}) \\
    c_{2t}^1 &= 0 \\
    c_t^2 &= \mu
\end{align*}
The interest rate is then $-1+\frac{q_t^0}{p_{t+1}}=\beta^{-1}-1$. I think this result is intuitive as the type-$2$ consumer wants to perfectly consumption smooth since their intertemporal elasticity is $1$ and the type-$1$ consumer will let them do that since they are risk-neutral. The type-$1$ consumer is compensated with the interest rate $(1+\beta^{-1})$ on the amount they lend in even periods, $\mu$.
Is there a better way to solve this than by conjecture? I think the conjecture seems natural, but is there a more direct approach?
Now, when $\alpha>\mu (1+\beta^{-1})$, I suspect the interest rate will rise in even periods but decrease in odd periods as the type-2 consumer demands more assets in even periods and is willing and able to supply more assets in odd periods.
However, I'm not sure how to make progress. If I make the same conjecture about prices being $q_t^0=\beta^t$ and $\lambda^2=\frac{1}{\mu}$, I find that \begin{align*}
    c_{2t+1}^1 &=\alpha \\
    c_{2t}^1 &= 0 \\
    c_t^2 &= \mu
\end{align*} And the gross interest rate is still $\beta^{-1}-1$. But this feels wrong since the type $1$ consumer is lending out $\mu$ in even periods and getting back $\alpha -\mu > \beta^{-1}\mu$ in the subsequent even periods. What I think I should be finding is that the interest rate is $$\frac{q^0_{2t}}{q^0_{2t+1}}=\frac{\alpha}{\mu}-1$$ so that consumption is as outline above. However, I'm not sure how to derive this and am not sure it is correct. If I conjecture that $q_t^0=\left[\frac{\mu}{\alpha}\right]^t$ then the interest rate is as I want it to be, but then $$c_t^2=\frac{\beta^t}{q_t^0}\frac{1}{\lambda^2} =\frac{1}{\lambda^2} \left[ \frac{\alpha \beta}{\mu}\right]^t$$ which blows up as $t\to \infty$ because $$\frac{\alpha\beta}{\mu}>\frac{\mu (1+\beta^{-1})\beta}{\mu}=1+\beta >1$$

Let $p_t$ be the price of the Arrow-Debreu security at period $t$.
Let's first look at an equilibrium where consumer 1 always has positive consumption: $q^1_t > 0$ for all $t$. In this case, the first order conditions for consumer 1 give:
$$
p_t = \beta^t p_0
$$
and the first order conditions for consumer 2 give (consumer 2 will always consume positive amounts):
$$
q^2_t = \beta^t q^2_0 \frac{p_0}{p_t} = q^2_0.
$$
The total resources for individual 2 are:
$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{t \text{ odd }} \alpha p_t & = \alpha p_0 \sum_{t \text{ odd}} \beta^t,\\
&= \alpha p_0 \frac{\beta}{1 - \beta^2}.
\end{align*}
$$
Total expenditures are:
$$
\sum_t q^2_0 p_t = q^2_0 p_0 \frac{1}{1 - \beta}.
$$
Equating the two gives
$$
q^2_t = q^2_0 = \alpha  \frac{\beta}{1 + \beta}.
$$
Then,
$$
q^1_t = \begin{cases} \mu - \alpha\frac{\beta}{1 + \beta} &\text{ if $t$ is even}\\
\mu + \frac{\alpha}{1 + \beta} &\text{ if $t$ is even}.
\end{cases}.
$$
Finally prices are such that $p_t = \beta^{t} p_0$ and we can normalize prices such that, for example, $p_0 = 1$.
Now, we see that $q^1_t \ge 0$ if and only if $\alpha \le \mu\frac{1 + \beta}{\beta}$.
If $\alpha > \mu\frac{1 + \beta}{\beta}$ we need to look for a different equilibrium. Intuitively, this will be one where $q^1_t = 0$ when $t$ is even.

Consider a case where $q^1_t = 0$ if $t$ is even and $q^1_t > 0$ if $t$ is odd.
Then if $t$ and $j$ are odd, we should have (by the first order conditions of consumer 1:
$$
p_t = \beta^{t -j} p_j
$$
In particular period 1 is odd, so:
$$
p_t = \beta^{t-1} p_1.
$$
Next, if $t$ is even then prices should be to high, so:
$$
p_t \ge \beta^{t-1} p_1.
$$
Next, by the first order condition of consumer 2, we have that if $t$ is odd, then:
$$
q^2_t = \beta^{t-1} p_1 q^2_1 \frac{p_1}{p_t} = q^2_1.
$$
If $t$ is even then $q^2_t = \mu$ (as $q^1_t = 0$).
So, by the same first order condition:
$$
\mu = \beta^{t-1} q^2_1 \frac{p_1}{p_t} \to p_t = \beta^{t-1} p_1 \frac{q^2_1}{\mu}.
$$
The total revenue of consumer 2 is
$$
\sum_{t \text{ is odd}} \alpha p_t = \alpha \sum_{t \text{ is odd}} \beta^{t-1} p_1 = \alpha p_1 \frac{1}{1 - \beta^2}
$$
The total expenditure is:
$$
\begin{align*}
&\sum_{t \text{ is even }} p_t q_2^t + \sum_{t \text{ is odd}} p_t q^2_t,\\
&= \sum_{t \text{ is even}}\beta^{t-1} p_1 \frac{q^2_1}{\mu} \mu + \sum_{t \text{ is odd}} \beta^{t-1} p_1 q^2_1,\\
&=p_1 q^2_1 \sum_{t \text{ is even}} \beta^{t-1} + p_1 q^2_1 \sum_{t \text{ is odd}} \beta^{t-1},\\
&=p_1 q^2_1 \left(\frac{\beta^{-1}}{1 - \beta^2} + \frac{1}{1 - \beta^2}\right),\\
&=p_1 q^2_1 \frac{1}{1 - \beta^2}\frac{1 + \beta}{\beta}.
\end{align*}
$$
So:
$$
q^2_1 = {\alpha} \frac{\beta}{1 + \beta}.
$$
This gives:
$$
q^2_t = \begin{cases} \mu &\text{ if $t$ is even}\\
\alpha \frac{\beta}{1 + \beta} &\text{ if $t$ is odd}\end{cases}
$$
Then using the resource constraints:
$$
q^1_t = \begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if $t$ is even}\\
\mu + \frac{\alpha}{1 + \beta} & \text{ if $t$ is odd} \end{cases}
$$
Finally,
$$
p_t = \begin{cases} \beta^{t-1} p_1 &\text{ if $t$ is odd}\\
\beta^{t-1} p_1 \frac{\alpha \beta}{(1+\beta)\mu} &\text{ if $t$ is even} \end{cases}
$$
Prices in even periods are higher than in odd period.
Note that prices can be normalized so that, for example, $p_1 = 1$.

Thank you for your answer! I haven’t had time to look at it properly yet, but from a glance I think you’re assuming both types of consumer have the logarithmic utility. However one has a “risk-neutral” intra-period utility function and one has logarithmic. I think the exercise is meant to focus on the impact of corner solutions on interest rates which are generated by violations of the Inada conditions.

Ok, I made some changes. Sorry for the confusion. Anyway, the model needs to be closed using the budget constraints of the consumers.

Very nice. Thank you for taking the time to write it out, it makes complete sense. Just to highlight a small notational difference, where you've written $q$ for consumption, I had $c$ for consumption and $q$ for the price of Arrow-Debreu securities, but it doesn't matter as it's clear anyway. Thank you again!
